# R: Generate variable in data.frame using minif on other columns

Tags: r, min

I have a data.frame that contains a variable for an obvservation date (`Portfolio.Date`), IDs (`Loan.Number`) and a status indicator (1-8) (`Current.Delinquency.Code`). I want to calculate a new variable that is true only the first time that the status indicator goes above 3 for any ID. In Excel I would write `=[Portfolio.Date]=minif([Portfolio.Date], [Loan.Number], [@Loan.Number], [Current.Delinquency.Code], ">3")`, but I cannot figure out how to do this in R. Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much!

What I am looking for is the formula for the [`Delinquent`] column in the below example Data, which jumps to "TRUE" the first time that the an observation of "Current.Delinquency.Code" for tha "Loan.Number" is above 3.

```
Portfolio.Date  Loan.Number  Current.Delinquency.Code  Delinquent
    2022/01/01      1            1                     FALSE
    2022/02/01      1            4                     TRUE
    2022/03/01      1            4                     FALSE
    2022/04/01      1            4                     FALSE
    2022/01/01      2            1                     FALSE
    2022/02/01      2            1                     FALSE
    2022/03/01      2            1                     FALSE
    2022/04/01      2            1                     FALSE
    2022/01/01      3            1                     FALSE
    2022/02/01      3            3                     FALSE
    2022/03/01      3            4                     TRUE
    2022/04/01      3            4                     FALSE
```

Comment: Provide example data intput, and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you correctly this is one possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

# to make it reproducable:
set.seed(1)
# sample data
df <- data.frame(Portfolio.Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2022-01-30"), by = "days"),
                 Loan.Number = rep(c(1,2), 15),
                 Current.Delinquency.Code = sample(1:8, size = 30, replace = TRUE)) %>%

# group by Loan.Number
dplyr::group_by(df, Loan.Number) %>%
    # order by Portfolio.Date
    dplyr::arrange(Portfolio.Date) %>%
    # check the condition and make a cumsum of it, returning only those where cumsum is 1 (frist occurence)
    dplyr::mutate(nc = ifelse(Current.Delinquency.Code > 3 & cumsum(Current.Delinquency.Code > 3) == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
    # ungroup to prevent unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 30 x 4
   Portfolio.Date Loan.Number Current.Delinquency.Code    nc
   <date>               <dbl>                    <int> <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01               1                        1     0
 2 2022-01-02               2                        4     1
 3 2022-01-03               1                        7     1
 4 2022-01-04               2                        1     0
 5 2022-01-05               1                        2     0
 6 2022-01-06               2                        5     0
 7 2022-01-07               1                        7     0
 8 2022-01-08               2                        3     0
 9 2022-01-09               1                        6     0
10 2022-01-10               2                        2     0
# ... with 20 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Would you mind explaining how the cumsum you mention would distinguish by Loan.Number? To me it reads as if that would just sum across everything, but the data you show below does not really look like that would be the case.

Comment: @JotHa cumsum() is a cumalative sum ... meaning: this sequence c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0) would read as c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2) using the function... just  try it out in r: cumsum(c(0,1,0,1,0)) ... and dplyr knows how to distinguish between Loan.Number because of the grouping group_by()-call in the first row (you could group by more than one variable also)